# Run Selenium Automation on Microsoft Tablet chrome browser (real device)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, windows

As a part of the Automation Test, I have to set up my test framework to run tests on Microsoft Tablet(real device), I am not sure how to connect my framework with the tablet device. please suggest some reliable approaches.
Selenium framework is written using C# and NUnit.

- Target browser is Microsoft Tablet's chrome browser
- Both are in the same wifi
- Continuous test is not considered for now
- Real device is preferred over the online emulators
- Windows 8.1 is the tablet OS version

Comment: What's the difference between running the tests on a desktop with Windows 10 and a tablet with Windows 10? I would expect you can just run the NUnit tests on the tablet, as long as you installed the required software and packages.

Comment: @Bouke I guess I won't be able to install all the required software in my tablet that runs on Intel Atom Processors and I didn't it try this approach yet though. Tablet OS is Windows 8.1 not windows 10. My bad, I corrected the tags.

Comment: @whereismymind
Did you really succeed on doing so, did you put selenium related libraries on tablet. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution helping me right own is

- Created a new project as a console app in Visual Studio and referred my actual test framework to it
- Running test using the .exe file extracted from the console app project
- Receiving an email report once the test is done as I have integrated emailable reports in my test framework